# Webapi 2 Attribute Routing

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-web-api2, attributerouting

I have the following routes set up in a user controller:

```
[EnableCors("*", "*", "*")]
[RoutePrefix("api/users")]
[Authorize]
public class UserController : ApiController
{
    [Route("")]
    public IHttpActionResult Get() 
    {
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("{id:int}")]
    public IHttpActionResult Get(int id) 
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("validateUser")]
    public IHttpActionResult ValidateUser()
    {
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [Route("verify/{identityId}/{emailAddress}")]
    public void VerifyUserEmailAddress(string identityId, string emailAddress)
    {
    }
}
```

The first three routes work just fine.  But the fourth fails with a 404. I'm using fiddler to make the call:

http://localhost:39897/api/users/verify/asldkfj/jb@test.com (post is selected)

Does post require data sent in the body? Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong and why the verify route is not being found?

Comment: the `.com` is the issue. if you add a trailing slash `/` it should work. ie `http://localhost:39897/api/users/verify/asldkfj/jb@test.com/`

Comment: ? its part of a valid email address.  How do I fix it?

Comment: sure its a valid email, but iis treats requests with file extensions as actual files and tries to find it on disk. when it can't find it then you get the 404

Comment: Thanks... How do I fix it?

Comment: does it work when you add the extra slash?

Comment: If i add a trailing "/" it seem to find the route just fine.  Thanks so much, I would never have thought of something so simple. Post it as an answer so I can credit you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.com` in the email is the issue.

Sure its a valid email, but IIS treats requests with file extensions as actual file requests and tries to find it on disk. When it can't find it then you get the 404 Not Found

If you add a trailing slash `/` to the request it should work.

ie `http://localhost:39897/api/users/verify/asldkfj/jb@test.com/`